# Unable to remove CSS property: Max-width:1200px

Tags: css, wordpress

Using the Villagio theme in WordPress, I have found that the listings have a max-width property which causes the image not to fit within the header. I have checked all of the CSS sheets and cannot find this command to remove it. Using the inspect element, I can simply remove this CSS style and it resolves the problem.

http://www.passionatacollection.com/accommodation/hh-luxury-condo-2bedroom/

What can I add to custom CSS to stop the display of this max-width style for the header background images within the listings?

I have tried various 'display none' in custom CSS which has not worked.

I expect to remove the max-width property affecting the background images in the listing headers.

Comment: You can try max-width: unset !important;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to remove a `max-width` attribute, you can use `none` value which is the default value :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

```
div.post-thumbnail {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Don't forget the `!` to `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

From inspect I can see that You added:

```
div.post-thumbnail {
  max-width: 100%important;
}
```

Change it to:

```
div.post-thumbnail {
  max-width: initial !important;
}
```